# shapefiles of the electoral zones of Rio de Janeiro

Tags: data-request, geospatial

I'm looking for the shapefiles of the electoral zones of Rio de Janeiro in 2018. Does anyone know where I could find it?

Comment: also posted here https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/303012/112869

Answer (score 3):

Somewhere in the IBGE perhaps? Sorry my Portuguese isn't great, but there is data for RJ here: https://agenciadenoticias.ibge.gov.br/agencia-sala-de-imprensa/2013-agencia-de-noticias/releases/21571-ibge-lanca-a-versao-2018-da-base-cartografica-vetorial-continua-do-estado-do-rio-de-janeiro

and other data on the ftp servers: ftp://geoftp.ibge.gov.br/cartas_e_mapas/ and ftp://geoftp.ibge.gov.br/organizacao_do_territorio/malhas_territoriais/malhas_municipais/municipio_2016/Brasil/BR/

There also seems to be some non-spatial data here: http://www.tse.jus.br/eleitor/servicos/cartorios-e-zonas-eleitorais/pesquisa-a-zonas-eleitorais

Comment: Thank you! I am still trying to find the shapefile of the electoral areas of Rio de Janeiro. There are many shapefiles on those pages, but I think they do not have the electoral zone shapefile available.